# Count number of users per country - Problem with SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have two tables.

- One containing countries with an ID and the geometry
- The other containing customers with a name, geometry and a boolean value showing if they are active or not.

```
Countries
iD     name     geometry
1634   UK       xxx
2357   USA      xxx
3345   Mexico   xxx
4694   Italy    xxx

Customers
name         geometry    statusActive
Hernandez    xxx         TRUE
Taylor       xxx         FALSE
Monte        xxx         TRUE
Winter       xxx         TRUE
Best         xxx         TRUE
Twist        xxx         TRUE
```

I want to find out, how many active customers there are in each country.

Step 1 - Join data: I could join the two tables based on the geometry. With ST_Contains I can test, which of the customers is located in which country. This works out well. I get as result a table from Customers which has additionally the column of the country ID. In addition, only customers with an active status are returned.

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT customers.*, countries.id
FROM customers
JOIN countries ON ST_Contains(countries.geometry, customers.geometry)
WHERE customers.statusActive IS TRUE
```

This is the resulting table

```
Customers
name        geometry    statusActive    id
Hernandez   xxx         TRUE            1634
Monte       xxx         TRUE            4694
Winter      xxx         TRUE            2357
Best        xxx         TRUE            2357
Twist       xxx         TRUE            4694
```

Step 2- Sum up the customers in each country. I do not know how I can achieve this. I already tried to use GROUP BY based on the country ID, but the query is running forever.
This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT covid.county.fips, Count (*) As Number
FROM covid.tweets_sub
JOIN covid.county on ST_Contains(covid.county.geom, covid.tweets_sub.geom)
WHERE covid.tweets_sub.corona_related is TRUE
GROUP BY covid.county.fips
ORDER BY covid.county.fips
LIMIT 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is how the desired result should look like:

```
NumberActiveUsers   ID
1                   1634
2                   2357
0                   3345    
2                   4694
```

Comment: That is the correct query for your data model, it's just slow because it has to work out the country of all of your customers by checking their geometry against every country's geometry. I imagine your first query was faster as you only fetched the first few rows, if you try to compute the country for every customer it will take much longer. I would suggest you alter your data model so that country_id is stored in customers as well as the geometry - you can look it up as you insert the row and you can fill the value in row by row for your existing customers.

Comment: thank you so much for validating the code. At least I can be sure that it would work correctly! Thanks for the hint how to adapt the data structure for a more efficient data storage!